# How can I associate an alias with the x.x.x.1 address in a docker custom network

Tags: docker, apache, dns

We have a set of services that run in a custom network. When deployed in production, there are some services that are exposed by the host machine on the `x.x.x.1` IP address of the custom network.  When deployed on developer machines for testing or whatever, those same services are exposed via a separate container in the custom network (and cleverly named `services`).

For various arcane reasons, one of the containers in the custom network is an Apache instance, and it has a proxy that relays through a well known exposed port on the host machine via its IP address (e.g., ProxyPass '/somepath' 'http://x.x.x.1:NNNN').  I know - it's awful.

Anyway, what I would like is to be able to say `ProxyPass '/somepath' 'http://services:NNNN'` and, in the production evironment, have `services` resolve to `x.x.x.1` while in the development environment resolve automatically to whatever container is named `services`.

I know I can just append an entry to /etc/hosts on the production instances, but that doesn't feel like the right way to do this.  There has to be another way!  Any ideas?